# New door in 47 inches wide corridor

Tags: doors, interior

I need to install a door in a corridor 47inches wide and 90 inches tall with laminated flooring..
The door we picked is 36x80...
How to I feel the gap on the side and top to fit my new door?
Do I keep adding 2x4 on both side?

Comment: Plenty of google hits for the search term "frame a rough door opening". Just be sure to keep the studs immediately adjacent to the door jamb dead plumb in both directions. In a perfect world, you'd cut back the laminate floor and attach the bottom plate to the actual subfloor. Be sure that the bottom plate runs straight across. Use a few long screws through the hinges instead of the shorties that come with a prehung door. If you have no seams in the drywall near the top corners of the door, you'll avoid cracking in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is a condensed version for a wall installation, but it should help a bit (I hope). The door should be centered in the width of the hallway. To do that you will need to build-out a wall to accommodate a 36 x 80 inch door. This is typically done with 2 x 4 inch stock. If it is pre-hung plan on a rough opening 1.5 inches wider and 2 inches higher than the door dimensions. Start by cutting 2 pieces of 2 x 4 to 47 inches. This is the bottom and top  plates. You will need to build out the side walls by about 5.5 inches on each side for the R.O width. Cut the studs closest to and on either side of the door to 81.5 inches for the R.O height. Cut a header to span the distance of the R.O plus 3 inches. Install header on top of the 81.5 inch (jack or cripple) studs.